# Java Map Values to Comma Separated String

Tags: java, csv, dictionary, guava, string-utils

Is there an effective way to convert java map values to comma separated string using guava or StringUtils?

```
Map<String, String> testMap = new HashMap<>();
testMap.put("key1", "val1");
testMap.put("key2", "val2");
```

looking for a way to convert testMap to a String -> "val1,val2".

Comment: Do you mean like `"map: " + map` does?

Comment: What do you mean by "comma separated string"?

Comment: Can you add example for your input and output?

Comment: Is this just for human reading, or so that you can later read it back through some software? If the latter, consider what happens if one of the values has a comma in it. You may want to use an established serialization format like JSON.

Comment: A "for each" loop is effective :-)

Comment: Did we answer your question? Is so, please pick an answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 32):

Here's how to do it in Java 8+ (doesn't require Guava, StringUtils, or other external libraries):

```
testMap.values().stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Comment: In Java 8 just use `String.join(",", testMap.values())` like in [Syam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40014896/201891).

Comment: Yes, that's MUCH cleaner.  Everyone should upvote Syam's answer

Comment: This can be useful when you're working with more complex objects, e.g: a `symbols` TreeMap ... `symbols.entrySet().stream().filter(x -> x.getValue().myParameter.size() > 0).map(Map.Entry::getKey).collect(Collectors.toList())));`

Answer (score 12):

Guava: `Joiner.on(',').join(map.values())`.

Answer (score 9):

In Java 1.8, a [join()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-) method was added to the String class that can do this.

Also `Map` has a function `values()` to get all values. map.values() are string type so just pass to String.join. Example:

```
Map<String, String> testMap = new HashMap<>();
testMap.put("key1", "val1");
testMap.put("key2", "val2");

String valueString = String.join(",",map.values()); //val1,val2
```

Comment: The method is available String.join is available from JDK 1.8

Answer (score 5):

You can use `StringUtils`:

```
final Map<String, String> testMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
testMap.put("key1", "val1");
testMap.put("key2", "val2");

String csv = StringUtils.join(testMap.values(), ',')); // "val1,val2"
```

**Note** that I changed the `HashMap` to a `LinkedHashMap`, in order to keep the insertion order.

Answer (score 2):

OK, here's my guess in case you want something like this (there's no clarification in your Question). This is done without Guava or StringUtils:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

map.put(1, 2);
map.put(3, 4);

System.out.println(map.toString());
```

Output:

```
{1=2, 3=4}
```

If you want to display the `values` as a comma separated list, you could use this:

```
System.out.println(map.values().toString());
```

Output:

```
[2, 4]
```

PS: Remove the `[]`s with `.replaceAll()` if you want

Comment: Or just values: `System.out.println (map.values());`

Comment: Or just keys! :-) `System.out.println(map.keySet());`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `makeString()` in [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/).

```
MutableMap<String, String> testMap = new UnifiedMap<String, String>();
testMap.put("key1", "val1");
testMap.put("key2", "val2");

String commaAndSpace = testMap.makeString();
Assert.assertTrue(commaAndSpace.equals("val1, val2")
  || commaAndSpace.equals("val2, val1"));

String comma = testMap.makeString(",");
Assert.assertTrue(comma.equals("val1,val2")
  || comma.equals("val2,val1"));
```

If you cannot convert your `Map` to an Eclipse Collections type, you can use `MapAdapter`.

```
MapAdapter.adapt(testMap).makeString();
```

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse collections.

Comment: @Donald Raab, I would have been great if the method name of MutableMap#makeString is something like `makeKeyString` for the key to a String value and `makeValueString` for the value to a String value. The method name `makeString` is not more self-described one

Comment: Great observation. These may be potential contributions to the library if you are interested in contributing. The method `makeString` on a map is actually inherited from `RichIterable`. In Eclipse Collections, a `MutableMap<K, V>` extends `RichIterable<V>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring MVC then this might work for you.

```
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

Map<String, String> groups = //List of Maps
List<String> targetList = new ArrayList<String>(groups).values());
String csv = StringUtils.arrayToCommaDelimitedString(targetList.toArray());
```

> Output: abc,def,ghi

Answer (score 0):

I think sorting may be important here. Not sure if map.values() returns in deterministic order, so i would prefer this:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("key1","val1");
map.put("key2","val2");

String formatted = map.keySet().stream().sorted()
                .map(k -> map.getOrDefault(k, "").toString())
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

At least this sorts by keys and is a bit more safe?